# NICs not visible for DA0S20MB6F2

Tags: networking, drivers

I have a motherboard that says **DA0S20MB6F2** on it. It was in an iron port box. I can't get Windows to see the NICs on it. Why not? What do I have to do to make the NICs visible?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a Dell PowerEdge 750 Server Motherboard, technical specifications [here](http://store.computerccw.com/images/750_specs.pdf).

Networking is defined as : Dual embedded Intel Gigabit NIC, Intel PRO/100S; Intel PRO/1000 MT; Intel PRO/ 1000MT Dual Port. You'd better check which one(s) you've got.

The Dell Network drivers may be downloaded from [Drivers & Downloads for PowerEdge 750](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&ServiceTag=&SystemID=PWE_ITANIUM_750&os=WNET&osl=en&catid=&impid=). The Dell drivers installations are normally harmless, since they don't install if the right hardware is not present.
However, you're quite limited in your OS choices: Windows 2000, Server 2003, Server 2008, Red Hat Linux.
Otherwise, you'll probably hope to find drivers on the Intel site.

[image]

Comment: Now *this* is an answer. Upvoted. The picture is a *nice* touch.

Answer (score 0):

Nics are Intel Pro/100 or 1000.

Another possibility is the previous owner used their own nics and disabled the mobo nics in the BIOS.

Comment: Check drivers for the dell powerEdge 750 server. As mentioned they are Intel gbit